# UIScrollView, changing zoomScale in updateUIView doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I'm having an issue with my SwiftUI code, where I am using `UIScrollView` as UIViewRepresentable to display photos that can be panned and zoomed. When the view is created (`makeUIView`), the image gets scaled to fill the frame - this works without a problem. But when I'm changing the image, and `updateUIView` gets called, the new image loads, but it doesn't scale to fill the frame, but instead shows at it's full size.

I verified using print statements that the setupImage func is getting called correctly from `updateUIView` when image changes. Also using `print(scrollView.zoomScale)` shows the correct zoom, but despite that, it doesn't render correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct UIScrollViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var image: UIImage
    @Binding var updateTrigger: UUID
    var frameWidth: CGFloat
    var frameHeight: CGFloat
    @Binding var currentScrollOffset: CGPoint
    @Binding var currentRelativeZoomScale: CGFloat 
    
    func setupImage(in scrollView: UIScrollView, with newImage: UIImage) {
        let imageView: UIImageView
        if let existingImageView = scrollView.subviews.first as? UIImageView {
            imageView = existingImageView
            imageView.image = newImage
        } else {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: newImage)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newImage.size)
        scrollView.contentSize = newImage.size
        
        let initialScale = max(frameWidth / newImage.size.width, frameHeight / newImage.size.height)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = initialScale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = initialScale * 1.5
        scrollView.zoomScale = initialScale

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.centerImage(in: scrollView, frameWidth: self.frameWidth, frameHeight: self.frameHeight)
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        scrollView.contentSize = image.size

        let initialScale = max(frameWidth / image.size.width, frameHeight / image.size.height)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = initialScale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = initialScale * 1.5
        scrollView.zoomScale = initialScale
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            centerImage(in: scrollView, frameWidth: frameWidth, frameHeight: frameHeight)
        }

        return scrollView
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        if context.coordinator.lastUpdateTrigger != self.updateTrigger {
            if let imageView = uiView.subviews.first as? UIImageView, imageView.image != self.image {
                self.currentScrollOffset = .zero
                self.currentRelativeZoomScale = 0
                
                setupImage(in: uiView, with: self.image)
                context.coordinator.lastUpdateTrigger = self.updateTrigger
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.currentScrollOffset = uiView.contentOffset
            self.currentRelativeZoomScale = uiView.zoomScale / uiView.minimumZoomScale
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: UIScrollViewWrapper
        var lastUpdateTrigger: UUID?

        init(_ parent: UIScrollViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return scrollView.subviews.first
        }

        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.currentScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
            }
        }

        func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.currentZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            }
        }
        
        func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        }

        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

        }

        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        }
    }
}
```